# Why does accessing an object literal with bracket notation and a key containing spaces result in undefined?

Tags: javascript

As it says in the title, I'm trying to access the value of an object literal using values from another object literal. This works fine when the values being passed do not contain spaces, but the ones that do contain spaces will return undefined. An example of the code:

```
for (var s in Skills) {
  console.log("Skill: " + s)
  console.log("Skill Stat: " + SkillStats[s])
}
```

---

```
export const Stats = {
  STR: "Strength",
  DEX: "Dexterity",
  CON: "Constitution",
  INT: "Intelligence",
  WIS: "Wisdom",
  CHA: "Charisma"
}

export const Skills = {
  Acrobatics: "Acrobatics",
  AnimalHandling: "Animal Handling",
}

export const SkillStats = {
  [Skills.Acrobatics]: Stats.DEX,
  [Skills.AnimalHandling]: Stats.WIS,
}
```

Output:

[image]

I've tried searching many variations of the title for solutions, but with no success. I'm still relatively inexperienced in javascript so please excuse me if any of this code is unorthodox. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You enumerate the property names of `Skills` but access and log the property values on `SkillStats`?

Comment: If you want to have a set of property ids that map to names via `Skills`, stats via `SkillStats`, etc., that means defining `SkillStats` with `Acrobatics: Stats.DEX, AnimalHandling: Stats.WIS` instead of computed property names.

Answer (score 1):

`s in Skills` loops over the property names in Skills. This determines the property name you are looking for: `AnimalHandling` (with no space in it).

The `SkillStats` object you are looking in had the property defined with: `[Skills.AnimalHandling]: Stats.WIS`.  That means the property name is computed from the **value** of `Skills.AnimalHandling` which is `"Animal Handling"`.

It simply doesn't match.

Comment: Alright, I understand where I went wrong, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

You enumerate the property names of `Skills` but access and log the property values on `SkillStats`. It seems you meant to use

```
const skill = Skills[s];
console.log("Skill Stat: " + SkillStats[skill]);
```

Or in one go:

```
console.log("Skill Stat: " + SkillStats[Skills[s]]);
```

Comment: This is indeed what I should have been doing, that did the trick, thank you